# Замена NULL на значение предыдущего значения

Tags: sql, sql-server

Делаю такой запрос на t-sql:

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN Sum_ IS NOT NULL THEN Sum_
ELSE COALESCE(Sum_, 0)
END AS first_Non_Null
FROM dbo.VIEW_1;
GO
```

Где идет обработка поля Sum_, если оно пустое, то заменяем его на 0, в противном случае оставляем без изменения. У меня вопрос такой, можно сделать так, чтобы сделать вставку не 0, а значения предыдущего числового значения.

Если, допустим, данный запрос вернет:

```
Index_data | Sum_
_____________________
20.10.2015 | 8
21.10.2015 | 2
22.10.2015 | NULL
23.10.2015 | 5
24.10.2015 | NULL
25.10.2015 | NULL
26.10.2015 | 6
```

Переделать его так:

```
Index_data | Sum_
_____________________
20.10.2015 | 8
21.10.2015 | 2
22.10.2015 | 2
23.10.2015 | 5
24.10.2015 | 5
25.10.2015 | 5
26.10.2015 | 6
```

Как это сделать? Хотел курсором перебрать, однако, хочется оформить это просто запросом или вложенными запросами.

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN Sum_ IS NOT NULL THEN Sum_
ELSE COALESCE(Sum_, SELECT Sum_ FROM dbo.VIEW_1 WHERE ????)
END AS first_Non_Null
FROM dbo.VIEW_1;
GO
```

или как-то так:

```
DECLARE @val nvarchar(30); 
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN Sum_ IS NOT NULL THEN Sum_
ELSE COALESCE(Sum_, Sum_.PREV....... )
END AS first_Non_Null
FROM dbo.VIEW_1;
GO
```

Такое возможно сделать?

Comment: Попробуй прикрутить join. Другой вариант - создать временную таблицу в переменной, сложить результат в неё, потом через переменную прогнать select и отдать его. Или как-то так. Но mssql позволяет использовать переменные со значениями прошлой строки в следующей, хотя там какой-то подвох был, что либо select, либо присваивание.

Comment: @pavel,  мне не нужно складывать значение, а просто от предыдущей записи значение получить. Если допустим на на третьей строке у меня NULL, то я беру от второй записи значение. Если на четвертой строке тоже пусто, то беру уже от третий записи.

Comment: О какой предыдущей строке идет речь, если у Вас в запросе нету `ORDER BY`? Порядок строк в этом случае может изменяться от запроса к запросу.
А вообще, если версия сервера позволяет, то используйте `LAG`.

Comment: у меня подобная задача, помогите пожалуйста решить. Пробовала варианты со смещением, но это не помогает вернуть последнее значение больше нуля , если до нужной строки 100 строк с результатом 0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Используйте функцию [LAG](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_lag_and_lead_functions.html):

```
SELECT index_data, 
coalesce(Sum_, LAG(Sum_)  OVER(ORDER BY index_data))
FROM dbo.VIEW_1;
```

Comment: Не совсем универсальный вариант... Сейчас по прежнему многие сидят на MS SQL 2008 r2...

Comment: @iluxa1810 а кое-кто - до сих пор на SQL 2000. Если вам нужно решение под конкретную древнюю версию SQL Server - стоит упомянуть об этом прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Верный ответ, только он не работает действительно на SQL вплоть до 2008.

Comment: IntegralAL, по ссылке, которую я дал в ответе, вы найдёте и универсальные решения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сделать через "хитрый" JOIN. У тебя есть запрос, который возвращает значения с NULL и значения без NULL.

Можно попробовать с чем-то типа этого поиграть :

```
JOIN table2 ON DATEADD(d,1,table2.date)=table1.date and DATEADD(d,1,table2.date) is not null
```

Comment: В table2 и в table1 у вас хранится одни те же данные. В чем смысл ваших сравнений данных из этих таблиц?

Comment: @IntegralAL, заметьте, что соединение идет не по =, а по текущая дата+1 и с условием is not null.

Answer (score 0):

@Elena Kalinina, попробуйте примеры для решения задачи.Данные примеры **подходят** для случая, когда идут подряд несколько пустых значений. Просто взять LAG(Значение) в этом случае не получится.
Возьмем данные из этой задачи

```
with data as(
select *
  ,lead(index_data,1,index_data)over(order by index_data) nextdate
from test
where Sum_ is not null
)
select t1.Index_data,coalesce(t1.Sum_,t2.Sum_) Sum_
  ,t2.Index_data from_date
from test t1
left join data t2 on t2.index_data<t1.index_data and t2.nextdate>t1.index_data
```

результат запроса. В колонке from_date приведена дата, из которой взято значение для замены null в текущей дате.

| Index_data | Sum_ | from_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-10-20 | 8 | null |
| 2015-10-21 | 2 | null |
| 2015-10-22 | 2 | 2015-10-21 |
| 2015-10-23 | 5 | null |
| 2015-10-24 | 5 | 2015-10-23 |
| 2015-10-25 | 5 | 2015-10-23 |
| 2015-10-26 | 6 | null |

Для более ранних версий SQL Server или других СУБД, где нет оконной функции LEAD, предлагаю посмотреть решение

```
with trn as( -- пронумеруем непустые значения по порядку даты
select *
  ,row_number()over(order by index_data) rn
from test
where Sum_ is not null
)
,data as( -- свяжем таблицу с самой собой и получим дату следующего непустого значения
select t1.Index_data,t1.Sum_
   ,t2.Index_data nextdate
from trn t1
left join trn t2 on t1.rn=(t2.rn-1)
)
select t1.Index_data,coalesce(t1.Sum_,t2.Sum_) Sum_
  ,t2.Index_data from_date
from test t1
left join data t2 on t2.index_data<t1.index_data and t2.nextdate>t1.index_data
```

Данные

```
create table test(Index_data date, Sum_ int);
insert into test values
 ('2015.10.20', 8)
,('2015.10.21', 2)
,('2015.10.22', NULL)
,('2015.10.23', 5)
,('2015.10.24', NULL)
,('2015.10.25', NULL)
,('2015.10.26', 6)
;
```

[Пример здесь](https://dbfiddle.uk/iyd84YcR)